# Error on start of "getLoadingManager.init" inside of button click in Android?

Tags: java, android, asynctaskloader

i am initializing loader in insideOnclick method of button but failed to do so and getting error becuase of third last  parameter when passing **"null"** it gives me error while passing **"this"**    also failed to do work.

```
    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if(userName.getText().length() == 0 || password.getText().length() == 0)
                {
            Toast.makeText(context,"UserName Or Password Should be Filled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        else{
    userName.setText("");
   password.setText("");
   **getLoaderManager().initLoader(1,null,null);** //here is the error 

                    }
                }
                });

            }
             @Override
                public  Loader<User> onCreateLoader(int id,Bundle args) {
                 loginLoader = new LoginLoader(context,userName.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString(),"2013-07-10 01:18:26");
                Log.i("login loader",""+loginLoader);
                 return loginLoader;
                 }

                @Override
                public void onLoadFinished(Loader<User> arg0,User proposals) {
                    Log.i("User",""+proposals.getUsername());
                    }
```

Here is the error List:

> 01-27 23:27:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(7777): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-27 23:27:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(7777): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   01-27 23:27:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(7777):     at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createLoader(LoaderManager.java:544)
>   01-27 23:27:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(7777):     at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl.createAndInstallLoader(LoaderManager.java:553)
>   01-27 23:27:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(7777):     at android.app.LoaderManagerImpl.initLoader(LoaderManager.java:607)
>   01-27 23:27:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(7777):     at com.mrfs.android.surveyapp.activities.LoginActivityService$1.onClick(LoginActivityService.java:58)
>   01-27 23:27:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(7777):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
>   01-27 23:27:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(7777):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
>   01-27 23:27:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(7777):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
>   01-27 23:27:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(7777):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   01-27 23:27:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(7777):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   01-27 23:27:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(7777):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
>   01-27 23:27:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(7777):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-27 23:27:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(7777):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   01-27 23:27:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(7777):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
>   01-27 23:27:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(7777):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
>   01-27 23:27:33.480: E/AndroidRuntime(7777):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   ****EDIT CODE: LOGIN LIST SERVICE.JAVA****

```
public class LoginListService 
{
SurveyDBHelper surveyDBHelper;
private final  static  LoginListService INSTANCE = new LoginListService();
public LoginListService()
{}
public static LoginListService getLoginInstance()
{return INSTANCE;
}
public User getLoginResult(String userName, String password,
            String apkVersion) {
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();
        formData.add("username", "kong");
        formData.add("password", "kongkong");
        formData.add("apkStatusDate", "2013-07-10 01:18:26"); // **HERE IS THE ERROR** 
        System.out.print("form data values:" + formData);
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(
                formData, WorkflowRestService.getInstance().getRequestHeaders());
        ResponseEntity<UserListItemHolder> responseEntity = WorkflowRestService
                .getInstance()
                .getRestTemplate()
                .exchange(WorkflowApp.getServicesURL() + "user/logIn",
                        HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,
                        UserListItemHolder.class);

        Log.i("response Entity Login", "" + responseEntity);
        UserListItemHolder userListItemInstance = responseEntity.getBody();
        Log.i("response Entity Body Location Function",
                "" + responseEntity.getBody());
        if ("true".equals(userListItemInstance.getApkStatus())) {
Log.i("locationInstance.getLocationListItems if", ""+ userListItemInstance.getUserListItems());
            return userListItemInstance.getUserListItems();


        } else {
Log.i("locationInstance.getLocationListItems else", ""+ userListItemInstance.getUserListItems());
            userListItemInstance = null;
            return userListItemInstance.getUserListItems();
        }

    }
```

Comment: are you using the support v4 package ?

Comment: no i am not using v4 package

Comment: what is your target version, are giving support to below version 11 also ?

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code and your marker, the `NullPointerException` occurs because you're passing in a `null` in the place of a *required* parameter.

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(1,null,null); //here is the error
```

According to the [LoaderManager Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html#initLoader%28int,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks%3CD%3E%29) the callback is required:

**Parameters**

- ***id*** A unique identifier for this loader. Can be whatever you want. Identifiers re scoped to a particular LoaderManager instance.
- ***args***   Optional arguments to supply to the loader at construction. If a
  loader already exists (a new one does not need to be created), this
  parameter will be ignored and the last arguments continue to be used.
- ***callback*** Interface the LoaderManager will call to report about changes
  in the state of the loader. **Required**.

It looks like you're already implementing LoaderCallbacks, you just have to pass your implementation to the `initLoader` method:

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(1,null,this);
```

Comment: now this error is removed but still null pointer exception in my service class that is reponsible to bring data from Service

Comment: Parsing time as a string can be a huge pain you'll have to deal with locales, formatting, etc. I would recommend to instead pass the time millis values (System.currentTimeMillis()). It's less human readable, but can easily be formatted a string where it needs to be displayed to users.

Comment: now i have change datetime datatype to String free from erros but still have little problems can someone help me

Answer (score 0):

Your date is in the wrong format. Use this instead:

```
2013-02-03T06:41:41.000Z
```

You have to put a T between date and time, a Z to the end, and add milliseconds.

Comment: Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2013-02-03 06:41:41': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2013-02-03 06:41:41': Can not parse date "2013-02-03 06:41:41": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd") (at offset 10))
01-27 23:44:44.195: E/AndroidRuntime(13215):  at [Source: libcore.net.http.ChunkedInputStream@421fdb78; line: 1, colum

Comment: the isssue is when i am trying to pass date to webservice let me edit code

Comment: THE ERRROR IS in added file LoginListService.java

Comment: I dnt want to change date, date should be same becuase i am getting data from service on the basis of this date

Comment: This represents the same date, it's just in a different format.